# Google Photos Screensaver not working on Windows 10 after upgrade

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, picasa

I recently upgraded a computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Prior to upgrading, the Google Photos Screensaver (included in the Picasa install) worked fine. However, following the upgrade, the screensaver fails to work. I have checked that it is still setup to work in the Screen Saver Settings window. On that window, if I click on preview, the screens flicker, go black for a minute, and then return to the way they had been before after a few seconds. And the screensaver never activates.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Picasa, didn't help.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the screen saver using the control panel item. E.g. set it to "Ribbons". Set the delay to 1 minute. Check that works. If it does, set it back to the Picasa screensaver and check if that works.

Comment: Other screen savers work. With this screensaver, when it is turned on for X minutes, than after X minutes of inactivity, the screen flickers black (same as when I click `Preview`) and the screensaver doesn't actually turn on.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  You have to select another visual effect setting other than "Pan and Zoom" such as "Cross Fade".  Windows 10 does not handle the Pan and Zoom setting and the screensaver crashes.